# How to sum cells up in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a enormous excel file, which has information about some ship containers and goods within them. Some of rows are False and I have to zero their value and add them to another row. Let's say:

[image]

How to change table on the right to the left?

Comment: Explain logic. You sum apple `1R` and `3R` (15+13=28) but why not `3R`?

Comment: oh, that was mistake.. I'll correct it.

Comment: If you just want subtotals of each Fruit, use Pivot Tables. If you need to keep the Ref# and Container # (even if you are faking the data because you are aggregating rows from different refs and containers) then probably you could do it with SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT. To be honest, easiest way would be Pivot Tables